# Universal Property of the Unit Interval

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

The unit interval is such that the square below is a pushout

[image]

and

$$ (\frac{id}{2})(0) = 0$$
$$(\frac{id + 1}{2})(1) = 1$$

For short, we have a diagram

[image]

Can this diagram above be used to characterize the unit interval? That is, if we have the diagram below in the category of topological spaces

[image]

where $a \neq b$. Can we construct a continuous map $\phi: X \rightarrow I$ that is unique with the property of making some diagram commute?

PS: I know Freyd's characterization of the unit interval. But I would prefer a characterization that does not explicitly refer to the category of bi-pointed spaces, nor to some category other than Top.

Comment: What you have written is literally the same as Freyd's characterization once you unwrap the definitions, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: The pushout is exactly what defines $I\lor I$, which is exactly the object giving Freyd's theorem ($I\lor I$ is the terminal coalgebra of an endofunctor), so it has that universal property

Comment: Ah! Great minds think alike :)

Comment: I want to prove that there is a unique continuous map $\phi: X \rightarrow I$ such that $\phi(a) = 0$, $\phi(b) = 1$, $\phi \circ f_1 = (\frac{id}{2}) \circ \phi$, $\phi \circ f_2 = (\frac{id + 1}{2}) \circ \phi$. Very likely it will turn out that the characterization I am seeking is equivalent to Freyd's characterization. But the wording is different, and it is not obvious that they are equivalent

Comment: One small detail of Freyd's characterization you're missing, though: the points $a$ and $b$ must be required to be closed in $X$.  Without that, for instance, you could have $X=I$ with the indiscrete topology.

Comment: (And I would disagree that it's not obvious they are equivalent.  Just write out what the definitions of all the words in Freyd's characterization are, and you'll get your statement.)

Comment: @Wofsey: you mean that I must require that the subsets $\{ a \}, \{ b \} \subseteq X$ be closed?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.